# How to create AWS Lambda dependency injection services with invocation lifetime scope?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, dependency-injection, aws-lambda

We can register services in AWS Lambda with AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton but only Transient and Singleton work as expected. Lambda doesn’t understand the scope of one invocation, so the service added with AddScoped will live during the Lambda life. So, its behavior is the same as a Singleton service.

How can I create AWS Lambda dependency injection services with invocation lifetime scope?

Comment: How are you resolving the dependencies in the lambda code? Are you manually resolving by doing `Container.Resolve` inside Lambda handler method?

Comment: With ServiceProvider.GetService manually for the root application service.

Comment: I'm fighting again this issue too. If you try to implement one transaction per request you'll have the same issues.